# When and how StreamReader should be disposed if underlying Stream should not be disposed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, stream, middleware

I want to deserialize `httpRequest.Body` twice in asp.net core 3.0 application: once inside middleware and the second time during the model binding.

Here is the code  from middleware

```
 var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpRequest.Body)
 var body = streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
 //some body processing
```

Pretty the same i have in my binding code

According to best practices, I need to dispose the `StreamReader` object here.
But if I dispose it in middleware I will get an exception during the binding - `Cannot access a disposed object.` as `StreamReader` will dispose used `Stream` as well.

So what should i do here ? Do not dispose `StreamReader` and allow GC to do it in the future?

Maybe this is something well-known and trivial, but I am totally confused ...

Comment: I don't think you can do this. I don't think the stream is buffered, and the client's only going to send the body once.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, So what would you advise to do in the middleware code ? The only option I see is do not dispose `StreamReader` but it has bad smell ...

Comment: So it turns out you can *turn on* buffering. You might try cribbing from [this example](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/re-reading-asp-net-core-request-bodies-with-enablebuffering/)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, wow, looks it work ! Thank a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the help and link provided by @Damien_The_Unbeliever the following code will allow us to dispose `StreamReader` and avoid `Stream` disposing and following exception in model binding.

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
{
    context.Request.EnableBuffering();

    // Leave the body open so the next middleware can read it.
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(
        context.Request.Body,
        encoding: Encoding.UTF8,
        detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks: false,
        bufferSize: bufferSize,
        leaveOpen: true))
{
    var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
    // Do some processing with body…

    // Reset the request body stream position so the next middleware can read it
    context.Request.Body.Position = 0;
}

// Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
await next(context);
```

}